# Do I have to delete memory in this case?

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct

Here is a simple program using dynamic memory.

My question is do I have to delete the memory at the and or the struct will take care of it for me?

```
#include <iostream>
struct Student {
  int grade;
  char *name;
};

void print(Student name);
int main() {
  Student one;
  one.grade = 34;
  one.name = new char[12];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    one.name[i] = 'a' + i;
  }
  one.name[i] = '\0';
  print(one);

  delete[] one.name;
  return 0;
}
void print(Student name) {
  std::cout << name.name << " has a score of " << name.grade << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Sure you have to delete `name`.

Comment: You have to `delete[]` what you `new[]`, and `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: @FilipKočica Like this? : delete[] one.name;

Comment: Look at @Someprogrammerdude 's comment :-) And yes

Comment: Yes, you must do after print(one); `delete[] one.name;`

Comment: Oh and you have a ***very big*** problem unrelated to when and where to `delete[]`, namely that C-style strings in C++ have to be *terminated*. A string must always be terminated by the `'\0'` character. So a string of 12 character needs space for *13* character including the terminator.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. I didn't notice.

Comment: Using `std::string name` would solve most of your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple rule of thumb- for each call of `new` you should have one call of delete. In this case you should delete one.name like so : `delete [] one.name`.

Of course you should do that after you no longer need its value. In this case this is immediately before the return.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocated `dynamically` using `new` or `malloc` must be freed up when you're done with it using `delete` or `free` otherwise you'll get `Memory leak`.

- Make difference between `delete` and `delete[]`: the first without subscript operator is used to deleted dynamic memory allocated with new for a pointer. The latter is used for deleting an array allocated dynamically.
- So in your case:

  ```
  one.name = new char[12]; // an array of 12 elements in the heap
  delete[] one.name; // freeing up memory

  char* c = new char('C'); // a single char in the heap
  delete c;
  ```
- Don't mix `new, delete` with `malloc, free`:

This is undefined behavior, as there's no way to reliably prove that memory behind the pointer was allocated correctly (i.e. by new for delete or new[] for delete[]). It's your job to ensure things like that don't happen. It's simple when you use right tools, namely smart pointers. Whenever you say delete, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use unique/shared pointers, you could use a constructor for allocating and a destructor for automatically freeing memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the raw pointer in your structure is an *observing* pointer, you don't have to delete the memory (of course, someone somewhere in the code must release the memory).

But, if the raw pointer is an *owning* pointer, you *must* release it.

In general, every call to `new[]` must have a *matching* call to `delete[]`, else you leak memory.

In your code, you invoked `new[]`, so you must invoke `delete[]` to properly release the memory.

In C++, you can avoid bug-prone leak-prone raw pointers, and use *smart* pointers or container classes (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::string`, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Structure does not mean it will handle garbage collection in C++
 there is no garbage collection so for every memory you allocate by using **new** you should use delete keyword to free up space. If you write your code in JAVA you wont have to delete as garbage collector will automatically delete unused references.

Answer (score -2):

Actually the structure won't freeup or delete the memory that you have been created. if in case you want to freeup the space you can do as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *c = new char[12];
    delete[] c;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: No! don't mix `new, delete` with `alloc, free`.